# The mathematics in understand anyons

Tags: gn.general-topology, mp.mathematical-physics

I've been about particles called [anyons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyons) which exist within a two dimensional framework. I've also found out that these particles can have an angular momentum equal to any real number. Normally, in quantum physics in a three dimensional space angular momentum can only take values equal to $j(j+1)$ where $j\in\mathbb{N}$. I've asked around and the I believe this answer probably gives the best reason why this is true:

> Starting in a 3 dimensional space, any path where one particle traces
>   a closed loop around another can be trivially contracted to a point
>   where no motion occurred.  This then means that the wavefunction
>   before and after the motion must be the same and so the wavefunction
>   can only be multiplied by a phase of $e^{i2\pi n}$ where $n$ is an
>   integer.  In 2 dimensions, however, the closed path around another
>   particle cannot be contracted to a point.  Thus, the wavefunction does
>   not need to return to its original form and may be multiplied by a
>   phase of the form $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is a real number.

Now, I coming from a pure math background and I've only recently begin to do research in physics. What are the topological 'reasons' for why this is true? Why is this not possible in a 2 dimensional space.

Comment: I'm not seeing a mathematical question here.  It looks like your question has more to do with a specific model, and you haven't quite made clear what model you're thinking about.

Comment: you can find the answer on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon#Topological_basis